# disable atomatic text options changes in word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, documents, autocorrect

Often when writing a document, either by moving the cursor from current text to a different part of the text, or when I change between languages in the text,
word will change the text settings on it's own.
(i.e. font, text size, incline-toggle, bold-toggle)

For example, if current language was hebrew and incline was off, if i switch to English and switch back again to hebrew, incline option will now be on.

I would like to find a way to disable all automatic text options, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the settings in my screenshot below, right-click to select the font.

(My example uses Chinese and English)

[image]